# Mutiple checkbox values insertion in db using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on web app using codeigniter framework and setting privileges for different type of users so I need to add approximately 35 rows in db for each user and each row have 6 checkbox values (0,1). I'm having difficulty while storing these values in array and sending to MODEL for insertion.

Here is Controller code:

```
public function set_priv(){

    $data = array(
        array(

            'type_id' => $this->input->post('priv_type_id'),
            'module_name' => 'Classes',
            'can_access' => $this->input->post('classes[0]'),
            'can_insert' => $this->input->post('classes[1]'),
            'can_delete' => $this->input->post('classes[2]'),
            'can_update' => $this->input->post('classes[3]'),
            'can_export' => $this->input->post('classes[4]'),
            'can_print' => $this->input->post('classes[5]'),

            ),
        //  ),
    );

}
```

HTML Form Code for understanding
Each check box for access, insert, update and delete privilege etc.

```
<div class="col-md-1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using multidimensional array to insert the data? 
if you are getting checkbox value in array finely.
I think it should be like.

```
$data = array(
        'type_id' => $this->input->post('priv_type_id'),
        'module_name' => 'Classes',
        'can_access' => $this->input->post('classes[0]'),
        'can_insert' => $this->input->post('classes[1]'),
        'can_delete' => $this->input->post('classes[2]'),
        'can_update' => $this->input->post('classes[3]'),
        'can_export' => $this->input->post('classes[4]'),
        'can_print' => $this->input->post('classes[5]'),
    );
```

Comment: I have 34 other records to add, this is code for just 1 as I'm just testing if it works or not.

Comment: then you should use loop.

Comment: Loop is not a problem but when I only use
'code' $this->input->post('classes') 'code'
It returns array 
'code'  array ( 0 => 'on', 1 => 'on', 2 => 'on', )  'code'
So then I can't find which checkbox was checked because It only returns number of checked checkbox not in correct order, mean it should return all checkbox with other as 'off' in array.

Comment: like this
  for($a=0; $a<count($data); $a++){
$this->modelname->functionname($data[$a]);
}

Comment: but when you only use what? i didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: $this->input->post('classes')

above code instead of

$this->input->post('classes[0]')

Comment: i think you should add value attr in html then you can find which value has checked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to codeigniter and stackoverflow.

Comment: Its fine. i am also new to stack overflow. did my answer helped ?
was that attribute issue?

Comment: Let me try, Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding checkboxes on view using any array then you can use same array to compare which checkbox is checked or which is not.

for example here is array to add checkboxes on view

```
$data[0] = 'can_access';
$data[1] = 'can_delete';
$data[2] = 'can_update';
```

on your view your code will be

```
<?php foreach($data as $key => $value){ ?>
  <div class="col-md-1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="classes[<?php echo $key; ?>]" />
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

after form submission you have to use same array to check i.e. $data array. 
code of your controller after submission will be

```
$builddata = [];
foreach($data as $key =>$value){
  if(isset($this->input->post('classes['.$key.']'))){
     $builddata[$value] = true;
  }else{
    $builddata[$value] = false;
  }
}
printr($builddata);
```

your array will build like this

```
$builddata['can_access'] = true/false;
$builddata['can_delete'] = true/false;
$builddata['can_update'] = true/false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access post data like that. See below code

```
public function set_priv(){
    $classes = $this->input->post('classes');
    $data = array(
    array(

        'type_id' => $this->input->post('priv_type_id'),
        'module_name' => 'Classes',
        'can_access' => $classes[0],
        'can_insert' => $classes[1],
        'can_delete' => $classes[2],
        'can_update' => $classes[3],
        'can_export' => $classes[4],
        'can_print' => $classes[5],

        ),
    //  ),
    );

}
```

Comment: I'm using your method but problem still remains same. Doesn't matter if I select random checkboxes It always turns ON from first checkbox.

I selected 'can delete', 'can_export', 'can_print' but result is array ( 0 => array ( 'type_id' => '4', 'module_name' => 'Classes', 'can_access' => 'on', 'can_insert' => 'on', 'can_delete' => 'on', 'can_update' => NULL, 'can_export' => NULL, 'can_print' => NULL, ), )

Comment: give value to each checkbox then check if available in array mark it as on